# Home router (or something) make a tunnel to Company

Tags: networking, router, vpn, remote-desktop

I have sort of some ideas, but not sure what it's called.

1. At home, I want the home router to connect to company vpn (something that direction), so I don't have to do a VPN connection on my computers. I can just ping and remote connect to computer on the company's LAN.
2. When I'm out, in public, I want to connect to company's VPN, and remote connect my home computer (through the tunnel from 1.).

Does anyboy have some recommendations what are those called?

Salut,

Comment: I do this with a VPN router (Cisco R series) and an IPsec Client App that allows me to connect to home and to customers with IPsec VPN connections.

Comment: Probably your company will just not allow it, as then every traffic from all your devices at home will be able and in some cases even forced to go through your company’s network. That is not just a gigantic security risk but also uses quite some of the available bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

> At home, I want the home router to connect to company vpn (something that direction), so I don't have to do a VPN connection on my computers. I can just ping and remote connect to computer on the company's LAN.

That's often called a "site-to-site VPN". Fundamentally it's still the same thing, with the router being a VPN client and just *routing* packets between LAN and VPN networks. (I'd even say it's the *more general* case of what a "VPN" really is, with typical client VPNs being a specialization.)

Some VPN protocols and client software (e.g. OpenVPN and IPsec) are frequently used for site-to-site VPNs, whereas proprietary products (e.g. AnyConnect) tend to focus on the specific case of "one-device client VPN" and with them it can range between annoying to impossible.

Make sure your company's IT team or network admins approve of this – they might not want your smart fridge to have access to their internal network. (Many corporate VPN clients aren't just VPN clients, but also agents that check the computer's overall security status, e.g. whether the latest updates are installed.)

And, besides the security issue, your router probably won't support the VPN protocol that the company uses – if it even supports VPN connections at all – so if the site-to-site VPN is established, it might end up being a custom setup just for you alone.

> When I'm out, in public, I want to connect to company's VPN, and remote connect my home computer (through the tunnel from 1.).

*Still* technically the same – packets routed from one network to another, then to yet another (from company to home over the "site-to-site" VPN), but may need a bit more involvement from the company's network team; e.g. they might be blocking inbound connections to VPN users in the first place.

I would strongly *not recommend* mixing personal and work infrastructure; use a separate VPN for such purposes. If your home network has an external IP address (i.e. no CGNAT), you can VPN directly into your home; if it does not, then find your own 3rd host that does (e.g. a cheaply rented KVM VPS would do just fine as a VPN "hub") or use hosted services that provide the meeting point (e.g. ZeroTier or Tailscale).